# Как правильно прочитать эту регулярку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
preg_match('/Text: .+, (\d+x\d+)[^\d]/si', $input, $output);
```

Конкретно: не понимаю для чего используется `[^\d]` после `(\d+x\d+)`, что дает в бою это, как я понял, отрицание?

Comment: Мне одному кажется, что наличие `[^\d]` в конце не меняет ровным счетом ничего? Или `s` - это модификатор нежадного поиска?

Comment: @andy.37 думаю не одному тебе. Но меняет, оно показывает что там не цифра. А значит после захваченных цифр должен быть какой то символ. а не конец строки

Comment: Прочитал http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php про `s (PCRE_DOTALL)` вообще запутался.

Comment: @Mike, блин, ну конечно...

Comment: @Mike то есть после `(\d+x\d+)` должен идти какой-то символ, НО НЕ ЦИФРА, так что ли?

Comment: @Plush `s` говорит что блок текста многострочный. вернее что `.` которая обычно обозначает _любой символ кроме перевода каретки_ начинает считать и перевод каретки любым. Без этого модификатора после `Text: ` и любых символов в тексте  ожидается запятая и цифры и т.п. в той же строке, что и `Text`. А с модификатором `s` запятая и цифры могут быть в последующих строках. Да [^\d] - означает любой символ кроме цифры

Comment: @Plush И да, [^\d] в данном случае перестраховка, `.` на ее месте сделала бы то же самое, т.к. все цифры уже захвачены `\d+` в скобках

Comment: @Mike то есть `[^\d]` следует оставить, по сути он на 100% ожидает что-то еще кроме цифр в конце строки и если строка будет заканчиваться цифрами, то выражение не сработает, верно понимаю?

Comment: @Plush Да, ты верно понимаешь, что когда цифры окажутся последними в строке - то регулярка не сработает. Но вот понимал ли это автор регулярки - это уже другой вопрос. Может он так своеобразно перестраховался, что бы \d+ перед ним точно захватила все цифры (хотя опасаться там нечего, точно захватит все).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Text: .+, (\d+x\d+)[^\d]/si
```

- `Text:` - обычный текст с пробелом на конце
- `.+` - несчётное количество символов, не считая символа разрыва
  строки
- `,` - обычная запятая с пробелом
- `\d+` - несчётное количество цифр
- `x` - обычный символ "x"
- `\d+` - несчётное количество цифр
- `[^\d]` - любой один символ, кроме цифр
- `s` - поиск в одной строке (без символа разрыва строки)
- `i` - не чувствителен к регистру

[Ссылка на разбор](http://regexr.com/3cdji)

Comment: `Text: AA, 24x2x356A`
`Text:      AA, 24x2x356A` - 2 последних примера по ссылке, они точно уместны под это выражение? я о двух `x` в строке говорю

Comment: @Plush, то, что выделено цветом является уместным. Я поэтому и привёл такую строку, чтобы показать, что два x не подходят для данной регулярки.

Comment: не понял вас. Все, что выделено цветом - подходит под регулярку. Два `x` быть в ней не может. Но примеры с 2 `x` тоже выделены.

Comment: @Plush, обратите внимание, что они выделены не полностью. Выделена лишь та часть, которая попадает под регулярку. Можете добавить свой текст и посмотреть, как это будет выглядеть.

Comment: Т.е. регулярка будет захватывать `цифры` `букву x` `цифры` и еще `один символ, но не цифру` ?

Comment: @Plush ,всё верно.

Comment: Попробовал тестировать, но конечный символ (т.е. [^\d]) не возвращается в `$output`. Выражение срабатывает по правилу, что в конце обязательно должен быть символ, который не является цифрой, иначе правило не сработает вообще.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33045/discussion-between-leqada-and-plush).